# Substring in Snowflake, string is the parameter value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

SET Date = '050120';

select SUBSTR("+Parameters!Date.Value+", 5, 2) [image]

I am passing the Date parameter value. Why is it not picking the date value?
It is showing the output as 'ra' which is shown in screen shot. I am expecting it to show 20.

Answer (score 1):

This will return 10:

SET Date = '050120';

select SUBSTR($Date , 5, 2);